# Add apostrophe between author and year using \citet

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

Based on the .bib file included below, I would like to add something like "[..] Grubbs' (1969) test [...]" in the body text of my LaTeX script, i.e. insert an apostrophe between the author's name and the year of publication. So far, I came up with the following (reproducible) example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%% .bib file contents
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Grubbs1969,
  author    = {Grubbs, F.},
  title     = {{Procedures for Detecting Outlying Observations in Samples}},
  year      = {1969},
  volume    = {11},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {1--21},
  doi       = {10.1080/00401706.1969.10490657},
  file      = {:Grubbs - 1969.pdf:URL},
  owner     = {fdetsch},
  timestamp = {2016-10-20}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

%% body text
\citeauthor{Grubbs1969}' (\citeyear{Grubbs1969}) test

%% bibliography incl. style
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```

First of all, this produces the desired result:

[image: grubbs_test]

However, I am wondering whether there is a more convenient way to temporarily modify the author-year separator passed on to `\citet`. Right now, there are two separate hyperlinks involved - one associated with "Grubbs" and the other associated with "1969", whereas both the apostrophe and the round brackets are not clickable at all (which is different from all other, i.e. standard in-line references created via `\citet`).

Comment: at least you could define your own cite command: `\newcommand[1]{\mycite}{\citeauthor{#1}' (\citeyear{#1})}`

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) to give us something to start working with?

Comment: Done @samcarter - still new to the LaTeX forum, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you only need this for one article, you could work with a `citealias`. This requires you to define the text, but the whole citation will be hyperrefed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%% .bib file contents
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Grubbs1969,
  author    = {Grubbs, F.},
  title     = {{Procedures for Detecting Outlying Observations in Samples}},
  year      = {1969},
  volume    = {11},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {1--21},
  doi       = {10.1080/00401706.1969.10490657},
  file      = {:Grubbs - 1969.pdf:URL},
  owner     = {fdetsch},
  timestamp = {2016-10-20}
}
\end{filecontents}

\defcitealias{Grubbs1969}{Grubbs' (1969)} 

\begin{document}

\citetalias{Grubbs1969} 

%% body text
\citetext{\citeauthor{Grubbs1969}' (\citeyear{Grubbs1969})} test

%% bibliography incl. style
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```

[image]